# Handle basic/full retreival of a database object in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a customer table in the db that stores the name, address etc, along with some photo, logo and other images.

I am using `entity framework` and I would like to know how to tackle the situation where I only want to bring back basic data about the customer in certain situations vs the complete data including images.

Should I have two entities, CustomerBasic and CustomerComplete

OR

have one Customer entity and fill it with two separate methods, FillBasic, FillComplete.

Any best practices? i'm new to EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your repository structure if any - with EF itself you can just use a projection with the properties you do want to a business object instance that represents a "basic customer", i.e.

```
var customerBasicList = context.Customers
                               .Where(...)
                               .Select( c => new CustomerBasic() 
                               {
                                 FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                 LastName = c.LastName,
                               }).ToList();
```

Performance becomes more important when you have a collection property (i.e. images in your example) in your entity. In your case you can take advantage of lazy loading to only materialize those properties when and if needed.

Comment: its not really a collection of images, but separately named columns. If I did not ask for c.LogoFileName (following your code example), it won't bring it back from the database?

Comment: @AlexJ: That's right - If you use a projection like this it will be mapped to `select FirstName, LastName from ...`

Comment: Can I just use Customer Entity (that has image fields) and using projection just not load them. so it will be c=> new Customer() but I don't load images just the name and address. Will it work the same way? i'm trying to avoid having two entities for the same object, basic and full.

Comment: @AlexJ: No, unfortunately you cannot project into an entity with EF

Comment: can you please send me a link where I can read on this projection stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be accomplished by projecting the query with the select clause.  For example ([taken from this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

```
using(AdventureWorksDB aw = new 
AdventureWorksDB(Settings.Default.AdventureWorks)) {
    var newSalesPeople = from p in aw.SalesPeople
                         where p.HireDate > hireDate
                         orderby p.HireDate, p.FirstName
                         select new { Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                                      HireDate = p.HireDate };

    foreach(SalesPerson p in newSalesPeople) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", p.FirstName, p.LastName);
    }
}
```

You can do a lot with this pattern.

Comment: Anonymous types are good in many circumstances, but I should mention that you cannot return the results of this projection or pass them to another method without creating an actual class to hold them.

Comment: yeah, i would need to return them to other methods so probably better to create a class called CustomerBasic.